# Is inline CSS inherited?

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

`<span style="color: #21584b;"><p>Text</p></span>`

That's an example of some code I have in my website. The colour is a dark green and it displays normally on my PC as well as on my Android phone. But, when viewed on an iPhone or an iMac the text is within the `<p>` tag appears white. I don't have any CSS in the stylesheet targeting just a `<p>` or a `<span>`. All of the CSS in the stylesheet has an additional class or an id.

I've removed the `<span>` tags wrapping the `<p>` one, but I have no way of testing it since I don't own any Apple devices myself.

So, the question is, will elements inherit inline CSS, like I've put here if they don't have any classes or ids overriding them?

Comment: `<p>` is not a valid child of `<span>` so chances are some browsers are "correcting" your invalid HTML and the result is not what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the other way round (`span` inside `p`), that's valid HTML and will overrule any previous properties for `p`:

```
<p><span style="color: #21584b;">Text</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If the value of a property is `inherit` then it will copy the value from the parent element regardless of how it was applied to the parent element.

---

That said, a `<p>` **may not** be a child element of a `<span>` element. The differences you are experiencing are likely due to different browsers recovering from your invalid HTML in different ways.

Comment: And it likely has to do with the surrounding markup that's not shown, too - `<!DOCTYPE html><body><span ...><p>...</p></span></body>` behaves identically in all browsers, whereas a more complex layout is likely to be less than interoperable.